# Getting expr: syntax error on index

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Using this

```
OF=$(ps fax | grep 'php-fpm: master process' | awk '{print $1}')  
IDX=`expr index $OF ' '`
```

I get an error. The results of the $OF variable are:

```
27797 27495
```

What is the error here? I think it has to do with how the variable is being passed into the expression. Also, have tried putting ' quotes around the $OF variable to no avail. That just returns 0 as not found.

Comment: You can change the first line to.  `of=$(ps fax | awk '/php-fmp: master process/{print $1}'). However, if you have `pgrep` you better use pgrep.  Also Explain in details what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pgrep` to grep the **Process ID** of a process. This is the safest way there is. Some systems(legacy systems) don't have `pgrep` so you'd be forced to use something as `ps`.  In case you use `ps` You should consider the following. Your line uses `grep` and `awk` which is not necessary as you could handle all that using awk.

```
of=$(ps fax | awk '/[p]hp-fpm: master process/{print $1}')
```

As a side note. Don't use upper case for normal variable names. By convension, Environment variables are CAPITALIZED.

At this stage your variable `$of` will hold the process id of the `php-fpm`.  Since your question is not clear, I'm not sure what `expr` is doing there.

Answer (score 0):

You need ***double quotes***:

```
IDX=`expr index "$OF" ' '`
```

Without quotes, the `expr` command looks like

```
expr index 27797 27495 ' '
```

which doesn't make any sense. 
With single quotes, you are passing `expr` the three-character long string
consisting of `$`, `O`, and `F` (which doesn't contain any spaces). 
It's almost always a good idea to put variables in double quotes --
and it's essential when the value might contain spaces or any other special characters.